# A wild riley I met

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I'm sitting in a bar browsing SE and then it happens,

> a girl comes right through the door and my prefix just leaves my lips.
>
> Sitting right next to me I already think about our future. I catch myself 
>   repeatedly saying my infix.
>
> Can you feel the electricity in the air? **I** can't do the first step, why isn't she a suffix.

Anyway, meeting her could be a *?* for my marriage.

Hint 1:

> For the suffix: My surname is "hode" so my friends gave me a funny nickname.

Comment: Since we really hadn´t many rileys in the past here is one. The spelling could be better but hope you have fun :)

Comment: I think @[Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41566/riley) would like this puzzle :D

Comment: Just that the hint is clear, the "I" is between infix and suffix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be a

> damnification

It fits the prefix description better, but obviously all credit goes to @hexomino and his answer :)

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be the best fit. +1

Answer (score 10):

I'm not entirely sure about the prefix but my guess is

> Meeting her could be a **justification** for my marriage.

a girl comes right through the door and my prefix just leaves my lips.

> **Just** - I read this as "my prefix, *just*, leaves my lips",

Sitting right next to me I already think about our future. I catch myself repeatedly saying my infix.

> **If** - which you would say a lot when considering the possibilities of the future.

Can you feel the electricity in the air? I can't do the first step, why isn't she a suffix.

> **Cation** - I wouldn't have gotten this without the hint but your friends must call you "Cat" (Cat Hode) and so you are looking for your cation (attracted to the cathode).

**I**

> As mentioned in the comments, the emboldening of the *I* indicates it comes between the infix and the suffix.

Comment: I like your solution:) I only had a different prefix in my head that fits the marriage part a bit better. Just think what could a guy say if he sees a hot girl/boy.

Comment: "She's a real beaut!" "Oh damn!" Oh please say it's not "ram"...

Comment: @iiiidk oh, It´s not ram but damn you wrote the word :D